# Can a 4th Gen Chromecast ("Chromecast with Google TV") work in a group with Chromecast Audio?

Tags: chromecast

I have five Chromecast Audio devices which produce 3.5mm/optical audio output from one source.   I also have a 1st gen Chrome TV with HDMI audio [*the "keyhole" shape*] which cannot play audio streams shared with Chromecast audio.  It will support Spotify, but not as part of the five Chomecast Audio devices in an audio group.

Can a 4th generation Chomecast (product name "Chromecast with Google TV", either HD or 4K) play a Chromecast audio stream shared with Chromecast Audio devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not actually added one, but the Home app implies so.

Both Chromecasts listed are the new HD with Google TV models and the old key hole shaped model is not listed as an option

[image]